# динамическое добавление условий

Tags: php

На сайте есть форма с selectами. В зависимости от того, что выбрано в селектах, происходит автоматическое заполнение других полей формы.

К примеру

```
if(($a=='1')&&($b=='2')&&($c!=3)) 
  $d==4;
else if(($a=='2')&&($b!='4')&&($c!=3))
  $d==5;
```

и т.д. Таких условий очень много. Там есть проверка на == или !=. Есть условия, что текущая дата больше или меньше определенной даты. И иногда приходится добавлять новое условие. Для этого открываю код, вспоминаю что там куда записано, это долго. Вопрос: как бы сделать этот процесс удобнее, чтобы например у меня, как админа, была определенная форма, куда я эти условия заносил. спасибо

Comment: Что вы пытались сделать чтобы решить эту проблему?

Comment: создал таблицу в sql 
a знак b знак c знак d
1  =     2    =   3   !=   4
и для всех условий прописал все варианты. Соответственно, каждый раз я обращаюсь к базе, загружаю оттуда все условия и по одному проверяю.

Comment: Какую таблицу? Добавьте определение в вопрос. Представьте себе что вы пытаетесь объяснить проблему не телепату, а обычному человеку.

Comment: Чтобы было удобно как пользователю, сделайте какую-нибудь страницу для себя, в нее добавьте нужные поля, в которые добавляйте необходимые значения. Эти значения записывайте в базу данных, а в коде считывайте их и стройте на их основании ваши условия

Answer (score 1):

Вы ничего не говорите о том, что за селекты, какая задача, не приводите примеры условий, которых так много. Возможно, обсуждение пошло бы по пути решения совершенно другого вопроса (См. [XY-проблема](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-xy)).

Поэтому можно давать только общие рекомендации.

Например, напомнить вам, что код должен быть ЧИТАЕМЫМ, а переменные -- иметь понятные имена. Сравните два варианта: `$a == 524` или `$ContractType == CONTRACT_WITHOUT_PREPAID`, что быстрее понять? Есть шутка про то, что в программировании всего пара действительно сложных проблем: инвалидация кеша и какие давать имена переменным, так вот тут есть изрядная доля правды.

Ваше желание создать дополнительную прослойку по хранению условий в базе само по себе никак не решает проблему, только вводит дополнительный слой абстракции (а как известно все проблемы, кроме одной можно решить введением дополнительного слоя абстракций).

Ну, напишете вы редактор формул на PHP, вместо программиста будет некий пользователь сидеть и писать `&& $a == 524` (точно как и вы также пытаясь вспомнить, что такое `$a` и что такое `524`), но почему вы думаете, что создание админки решило вашу проблему нечитаемости условий?

Точно также можно было бы задумываться о том, чтобы не админку писать, а поверх PHP написать новый язык язык написания логических условий -- и думать, что у вас получится нечто иное, чем кубики из привычных логических функций типа "И", "ИЛИ" и "НЕ" (ну разве что оставить пользователю только базис Шеффера, ЛОЛ).

Проблема может быть ещё и в том, что код хрупкий, потому что слишком много зависимостей между разными селектами, друг от друга, километровые if..elseif. Этого точно утверждать нельзя, поскольку вы сами подробно задачу не хотите описать -- но очень похоже, что это обоснованное подозрение. Можно ли упростить логику селектов, переделав бизнес-процесс? (Мы опять пришли к возможности XY-проблемы: нужна помощь либо аналитика, либо проектировщика интерфейсов).